# NestJS setup TypeOrm connection with .env and @nestjs/config

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, dotenv

I'm trying to find the most legal way to set up NestJS database using .env file. That is I want to use `@nestjs/config` package for importing .env variables and use them in the TypeOrmModule.

It seems I need to use `TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync`.

I'm trying to do it like that:

```
// app.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: TypeOrmConfigService,
    }),
    ...
  ],

})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then, there's `TypeOrmConfigService`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions, TypeOrmOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
})
export class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      type: 'mysql',
      host: this.configService.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
      username: this.configService.get('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
      password: this.configService.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
    };
  }
}
```

The last one is incorrect: `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmConfigService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context.`

How to fix it?
Or (the most preferred) is there anywhere an example of NestJs + TypeOrm + @nestjs/config + .env (outside of the repo, with DATABASE_PASSWORD) + config (I mean npm package config that processes config/development.yml, config/production.yml etc.)?

It seems that I'm looking for a very standard thing, the hello world, that should be a start of every NestJS project, but I found difficulties combining @nestjs/config and TypeOrm.

Upd. If I replace `@Module` with `@Injectable`, the error is exactly the same:

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ NODE_ENV=development nodemon
[nodemon] 1.19.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /home/kasheftin/work/pubngn4/nestjs-course-task-management/src/**/*
[nodemon] starting `ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts`
[Nest] 25384   - 09/01/2020, 8:07 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 25384   - 09/01/2020, 8:07 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +11ms
[Nest] 25384   - 09/01/2020, 8:07 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 25384   - 09/01/2020, 8:07 PM   [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 25384   - 09/01/2020, 8:07 PM   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmConfigService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context. +1ms
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmConfigService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context.
    at Injector.lookupComponentInExports (/home/kasheftin/work/pubngn4/nestjs-course-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:180:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (/home/kasheftin/work/pubngn4/nestjs-course-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:143:33)
    at resolveParam (/home/kasheftin/work/pubngn4/nestjs-course-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:96:38)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/home/kasheftin/work/pubngn4/nestjs-course-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:112:27)
    at Injector.loadInstance (/home/kasheftin/work/pubngn4/nestjs-course-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:78:9)
    at Injector.loadProvider (/home/kasheftin/work/pubngn4/nestjs-course-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:35:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (/home/kasheftin/work/pubngn4/nestjs-course-task-management/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:41:9)
 1: 0xa2afd0 node::Abort() [/home/kasheftin/.nvm/versions/node/v14.3.0/bin/node]
 2: 0xa9e7a9  [/home/kasheftin/.nvm/versions/node/v14.3.0/bin/node]
 3: 0xc06bab  [/home/kasheftin/.nvm/versions/node/v14.3.0/bin/node]
 4: 0xc08156  [/home/kasheftin/.nvm/versions/node/v14.3.0/bin/node]
 5: 0xc087d6 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/home/kasheftin/.nvm/versions/node/v14.3.0/bin/node]
 6: 0x13a9f19  [/home/kasheftin/.nvm/versions/node/v14.3.0/bin/node]
Aborted (core dumped)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 18):

It's my working script with Postgres in app.module.ts, but for MySQL will be very similar. And sometimes before rebuild need to remove dist folder manually - when DB can't synchronize.

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';


@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],      
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres' as 'postgres',
        host: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_HOST'),
        port: parseInt(configService.get<string>('DATABASE_PORT')),
        username: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_USER'),
        password: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_PASS'),
        database: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_NAME'),
        entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: true,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
```

.env in root folder

```
DATABASE_USER=
DATABASE_PASS=
DATABASE_HOST=
DATABASE_NAME=
DATABASE_PORT=
```

Answer (score 13):

on database.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: configService.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('DATABASE_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
        entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
        synchronize: true,
      }),
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

on app.module.ts

```
import { DatabaseModule } from './database/database.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({}),
    DatabaseModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This works for me

Comment: Thank you so much, been struggling with this!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with this I just add the following:

```bash
import 'dotenv/config';
```

my app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { typeOrmConfig } from '../ormconfig';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(), TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig)],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And my ormconfig looks like this:

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import 'dotenv/config'; // <- this line is the important

const config: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
};
export const typeOrmConfig = config;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `TypeOrmConfigService` should not be a `@Module()`. It should be `@Injectable()`. Everything else looks fine.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions, TypeOrmOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      type: 'mysql',
      host: this.configService.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
      username: this.configService.get('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
      password: this.configService.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work. The error is the same. It seems the config service is not passed to the constructor. That's why I tried to convert `@Injectable` to `@Module` because the last supports import prop, but still something is missing here.

Comment: What's the error you get when you use `@Injectable()` rather than `@Module()`? This should be a `provider` so it should be `@Injectable()`. I've used this pattern before

Comment: The error is exactly the same, Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmConfigService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context. Maybe isGlobal does not work as expected?

Comment: Can you add the full error to the original question?

Comment: Done. Done. Done.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of Nest are you running? I haven't seen an error like that in a good while.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
// app.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    }),
    ...
  ],

})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is still relevant, however, I think this is whats going on.

The error that you see "Nest cant't resolve..." means that you are trying to inject a class using dependency injection, however Nest can't find this dependency in the dependencies container.

In order to resolve the issue, you need to add ConfigService (the failed to resolve dependency) to app.module.ts Providers section.

Something  like that:

```
@Module({
   imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot(),
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: 'mysql',
          host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
          username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
          password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        }),
        ...
   ],
   providers: [
        ConfigService
   ]
    
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simple and Easy Way to do it**

npm i @nestjs/config

```
 @Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      name: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          type: 'mysql',
          host: configService.get(`DATABASE_HOST`),
          port: configService.get(`DATABASE_PORT`),
          username: configService.get('DB_USER'),
          database: configService.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
          password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
          entities: [__dirname + '/../entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
          synchronize: false,
          logging: true,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
```

Comment: Why are you using `async` for the `useFactory`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file (in this case the file is database.provider.ts) the file will export an array of connections.

```js
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
export const databaseProviders = [
  TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: configService.get('PGHOST'),
      port: +configService.get<number>('PGPORT'),
      username: configService.get('PGUSER'),
      password: configService.get('PGPASSWORD'),
      database: configService.get('PGDATABASE'),
      entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: false,
      logging: true,
    }),
  }),
];
```

Then import it in your database.module.ts

```js
import { databaseProviders } from './database.provider';
import { DatabaseService } from './database.service';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
@Module({
  imports: [...databaseProviders],
  providers: [DatabaseService],
  exports: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

And that's all, you can add multiple connections in your database.provider.ts if you want it, also, don´t forget to create the .env and import the database module in your root module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "[nestjs-easyconfig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-easyconfig)", i use it for multi .env (e.g: .env.development, .env.production' it's almost same with nestjs/config. you can check my [github repo](https://github.com/danudenny/nestjs_multienv)

Answer (score 1):

you can spit it to another module
**typeorm.module.ts**

```
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        database: config.get<string>('DATABASE'),
        username: config.get<string>('USERNAME'),
        password: config.get<string>('PASSWORD'),
        host: config.get<string>('HOST'),
        port: parseInt(config.get('PORT')),
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: true,
        type: 'postgres',
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class TypeormConfigModule {}
```

**main app.module.ts**
*import like this**

```
import { TypeormConfigModule } from './config/database/typeorm.module';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';


@Module({
  imports: [
    CaslModule,
    TypeormConfigModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: ['env/dev.env', 'env/prod.env', 'env/rom.env'],
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
  
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

** env is folder name and prod.env is env file or you can put it directly at app.module.ts  as above**

**ANOTHER METHOD TO USE ENV TOGETHER IN APP.MODULES.TS DIRECTLY**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    CaslModule,
   TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        database: config.get<string>('DATABASE'),
        username: config.get<string>('USERNAME'),
        password: config.get<string>('PASSWORD'),
        host: config.get<string>('HOST'),
        port: parseInt(config.get('PORT')),
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: true,
        type: 'postgres',
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
]
}),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: ['env/dev.env', 'env/prod.env', 'env/rom.env'],
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
  
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: The last method works for me. Thanks !
You can also use :

type: config.get<any>('TYPE')   (in env file : TYPE=postgres)
synchronize: config.get<boolean>('SYNCHRONIZE') (in env file : SYNCHRONIZE=true)

Answer (score 1):

for me I just  add  this as my example

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmOptionsFactory, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import{Config} from'./config'
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseConnectionService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      name: 'default',
      type: 'postgres',
      host: this.configService.get<string>("DATABASE_HOST"),
      port: Number(this.configService.get<number>("DATABASE_PORT")) ,
      username: this.configService.get<string>("DATABASE_USERNAME"),
      password: this.configService.get<string>("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
      database: this.configService.get<string>("DATABASE_DB"),
      synchronize: true,
      sslmode:"disable",
      logging: true,  
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    
      migrations: [__dirname + "/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}"],
      migrationsRun: false,
      maxQueryExecutionTime: 0.1 /** To log request runtime */,
      cli: {
        migrationsDir: __dirname + "/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}",
      },
      
      
    }
  }
}
```

in the app.module.ts just  add  this  code in  import  section

```
imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),

    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: DatabaseConnectionService,
    })]
```

Answer (score 1):

For accessing .env file outside the src folder you have to import dotenv module

data-source.ts (outside the src)

```
    import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
    dotenv.config(); 
    import entities from 'src/common/entities';
    import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
    
    export const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
      type: 'postgres',
      port: +process.env.DB_PORT,
      username: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      entities: entities,
      synchronize: false,
      migrations: ['dist/db/migrations/*.js'], //migrations
    };
    
    const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
    
    export default dataSource;
```

app.module

```
   @Module({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(dataSourceOptions),
      ],
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [AppService],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only import `ConfigModule` to `TypeOrmCoreModule`:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule], // import ConfigModule
  useClass: TypeOrmConfigService,
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a **.env** file in the root of your project and add your database connection information:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME=your_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_password
DB_DATABASE=your_database
```

create a TypeORM configuration `ormconfig.js` in root dir

```
module.exports = {
type: 'postgres', // Change this to your database type
host: process.env.DB_HOST,
port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT, 10),
username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'], // Point to your entity files
synchronize: false, // Set this to true only for development
};
```

create config model config.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

Or in `app.model.ts` import configuration

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        type: process.env.DB_TYPE, // e.g., 'postgres'
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT, 10),
        username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: false, // Set this to true only for development
      }),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your `ConfigService` GLOBAL