# TypeORM .env config not picked up in NestJS production build

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, nestjs, typeorm

I am working on a NestJS application accessing a postgres database through TypeORM. Everything works great in development mode (`npm run start:debug`). However, after building with `npm run build` and trying to run the application via `node /dist/main.js`, it fails to start with the following error:

```
error: password authentication failed for user "(my system user name)"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/(my system user name)/application/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
```

The app.module code is rather strait-forward:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
...
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
        ...
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            isGlobal: true,
        }),
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The TypeORM configuration is stored in an `.env` file. I also copy it to the `dist` folder after build. Trying to get this to work since days now - doesn't have to be through an `.env` file as long as it works in both development and production. Any idea why the configuration isn't picked up in production?

**Edit:** I have also tried several other configuration approaches like descriped in [NestJS setup TypeOrm connection with .env and @nestjs/config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678216) for example. Partially worked in development, but never in the production build.

Comment: paste your code where you pass the envs to typeorm configuration.

Comment: The code shown above doesn't even utilize nests ConfigModule/ConfigService. TypeORM configuration is done through env-attributes described [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-ormconfig.md#using-environment-variables). The `.env` file is placed next to `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue didn't have anything to do with TypeORM / NestJS. I simply used the configuration hardwired on another place in the application. Anyway, this is the Nest configuration that fits my needs best:

```
import settings from './config/settings';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            load: [settings],
            isGlobal: true,
        }),
        
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) =>
                Object.assign({}, configService.get<TypeOrmModuleOptions>('database'), {
                    entities: [
                        (entity classes, auto-resolution does not work),
                        ...
                    ],
                })
        }),
        ...
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And the corresponding configuration file `/config/settings.ts`:

```
export default () => ({
    database: {
        type: ...,
        host: ...,
        port: ...,
        username: ...,
        password: ...,
        database: ...,
        synchronize: ...,
        logging: ...
    },
});
```