# Set role for all TypeORM connections through NestJS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using TypeORM by way of NestJS to connect to a PostgreSQL database.  For every connection I make to the database, I need to 'SET ROLE my-service', preferably just once when the connection is established.  What are my options?

I have tried to find a way using the config that's passed to TypeOrmModule.forRoot().  I've considered the possibility that I can issue instructions to the PostgreSQL client ahead of time, but I don't have a strong sense of how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

*Please scroll to Update 2, per your unpated question.*

---

###### Option 1: As an `injectable service`

You can create a service `SomeTypeOrmConfigService` as an `@Injectable()`, and then inject it like so.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions, TypeOrmOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/typeorm';


// create your injectable here
@Injectable()
export class SomeTypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      type: 'mysql',
      host: this.configService.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
      username: this.configService.get('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
      password: this.configService.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
    };
  }
}
```

---

###### Option 2: Save the information in a common `.env`, or b) another approach `database.provider.ts` file and export that copied ans./credit to [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64127695/6085193)

```js
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export const databaseProviders = [
  TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: configService.get('PGHOST'),
      port: +configService.get<number>('PGPORT'),
      username: configService.get('PGUSER'),
      password: configService.get('PGPASSWORD'),
      database: configService.get('PGDATABASE'),
      entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: false,
      logging: true,
    }),
  }),
];
```

Then import it in your database.module.ts

```js
import { databaseProviders } from './database.provider';
import { DatabaseService } from './database.service';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
@Module({
  imports: [...databaseProviders],
  providers: [DatabaseService],
  exports: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

And that's all, you can add multiple connections in your database.provider.ts if you want it, also, don´t forget to create the .env and import the database module in your root module.

---

## Update Answer (V2) to updated question

*In a nutshell..* **I think you are missing** a) session module like `nestjs-session` , once you use that you can optionally b) cache it in your role with your session object

Step 1: use [nestjs-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-session)

Step 2: Now you can have access/use `role` in the `session` property object of your `request`

Step 3: You can then make it an injectable or a user factory with the help of the `NestSessionOptions`

---

### *My humble recommendation*, save yourself time, use a pre-rolled package as a decorator.. try this [package from here](https://github.com/iamolegga/nestjs-roles) - *use their sample ref. below* ->

> `npm i nestjs-roles`

#### 1. Create Your roles

```
// role.enum.ts

export enum Role {
  ADMIN = 'ADMIN',
  USER = 'USER',
  MODERATOR = 'MODERATOR',
}
```

#### 2. Let's say you use `nestjs-session` and keep role in session property object of request. So then *create guard with getRole callback*:

```
// roles.guard.ts

import { ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { createRolesGuard } from 'nestjs-roles';
import { Role } from './role.enum';

function getRole(context: ExecutionContext) {
  const { session } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  if (!session) {
    return;
  }
  return (session as { role?: Role }).role;
}

export const Roles = createRolesGuard<Role>(getRole);
```

#### 3. After that we can set Roles guard globally (don't forget to pass Reflector instance):

```
// bootstrap.ts

import { NestFactory, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Roles } from './roles.guard';

const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

const reflector = app.get<Reflector>(Reflector);
app.useGlobalGuards(new Roles(reflector));
```

#### 4. All settings are done. Now you can set up access in your controllers:

```
// secrets.controller.ts

import { Roles } from './roles.guard';

@Controller('secrets')
@Roles.Params(true) // setup access on Controller for users with any existing role
export class SecretsController {

  @Get('my')
  async readMy() {
    // ...
  }

  @Patch(':id')
  @Roles.Params(Role.ADMIN) // override access on certain handler
  async update() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Either I am misunderstanding your message, or my problem description was inadequate.  I am not having trouble making connections.  In fact, I am setting up connections in a way very similar to yours.  I am having trouble telling TypeORM "now that you've made a connection for me, issue 'SET ROLE my-service'."  I don't see how I can leverage the information you posted to add that detail to the business of creating connections.

Comment: No worries, all good, thanks for the clarification. Have you tried the role guard service, let me add something for you and maybe some links to help you.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Thank you.  However, you're still not addressing the problem.  I need to set a role ***on each database connection***.  Think of connecting to the database using a database admin tool or some sort, and executing "SET ROLE myrole".  You would be altering the way that the database responds to requests on that connection.  I need to do that to all connections that TypeORM is making.